# Regular expression to capture selected value in the drop down list

Tags: regex

I want to create a regex which gives result for the selected field in a drop down list for a particular id.

For example: if I pass **id="countries"** the result should be **India** (since India is selected) or **id="Gender"** the result should be **Male**.

```
<select id='countries'>
    <optionvalue='0'>All Categories</option>
    <option value='1'>USA</option>
    <option value='2'>China</option>
    <option selected='selected' value='3'>India</option>
    <option value='4'>Japan</option>
</select>

<select id='Gender'>
    <option value='0'>All Categories</option>
    <option selected='selected' value='1'>Male</option>
    <option value='2'>Female</option>
</select>
```

**Note: Consider above HTML as a plane text.**

Comment: How is this related to regex?

Comment: What does it have to do with a regex? Is it a webpage (DOM) or a static text?

Comment: Actually its a response data, we want to filter selected data out, consider it as a plane text, thanks

Comment: @AmitChauhan use HTML parser, regexing HTML is a pain in the ass.

Comment: Actually we r following a standard, we r fetching data using regex from XML, Json, and HTML. hence I cannot use HTML parser specifically.

Comment: @AmitChauhan you can (and should) use HTML parser for HTML, I am not sure why are you bringing up JSON and XML.

Comment: Please try to understand, from the server we may get data as XMP, JSON or HTML, hence we r using regex to filter out the data.

Comment: @AmitChauhan I understand, you post a piece of HTML and ask how to extract information from HTML. JSON doesn't have `select` elements with options and stuff, this question was posted about HTML. Yes, for JSON you should use JSON parser for XML - XML parser and so on.

Comment: @AmitChauhan how complicated can your HTMLs be? If they can get complicated regex really is a bad choice. And if they're simple like your example - not only is that HTML but a valid XML as well, you could use your solution for that here as well I suppose.

Comment: @Deltharis for now we have tried with simple input fields in HTML, For Example: If my HTML input is "<input id="name" value="Amit"/>" my regex will be: (?<=id="name" value=")(.*?)(?="), so that i can get the value as Amit (here I m telling regex to get the value only if id="name", hence it will not fetch other unwanted values) but now it is getting complicated, specially in the case of drop down list . hence I need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting HTML data using regex is a very very *very* bad idea. It's complicated and inefficient. You are better off using a HTML parser  (such as JSoup or BeautifulSoup) for HTML, a JSON library for parsing JSON, etc.

That being said, here is a regex that should work as long as the id is quoted. If your id is in a variable called `id`, then your regex will be

```java
regex = "<select[^>]*? id=['\"]" + id
        + "['\"].*?<option[^>]*? selected[^>]*?>([^<]*)";
```

Note that for this to work, the select with that id must actually have a selected option.

Comment: Its working, but only if all the content is in single line, for multi line its not working.

Comment: @AmitChauhan You need to make dot match newlines. Enable the `DOTALL` modifier in whatever language you are using (all regex libraries have one).